# Actionscript 2.0 mx.managers.CreatePopUp dialog triggers onRollOver for events underneath it

Tags: flash, actionscript, dialog, modal-dialog, rollover

All,

On the main stage I have a button that is highlighted on rollover. I am using mx.managers.CreatePopUp to create a dialog box that pops up and takes user information. When the dialog box appears above the button, mousing over the dialog box triggers the highlight for the button beneath it.

Can you provide some suggestions as to what the issue might be caused by?

(I am fairly new to Flash so any suggestions would be helpful. Just looking for things to experiment with to get the correct behavior.)

Other info that might be helpful:
I've noticed that when I create a modal version of the dialog box, this behavior does not occur. Dismissing the modal dialog disables the entire stage. Fixing this issue would also solve my problem, but I've been unsuccessful thus far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're new to Flash why are you using AS2?  You'd be better off using the latest tools and language and frameworks.  They're better and you'll get faster responses to questions.

Comment: Agreed with @Samuel Neff.. AS3 is ridiculously superior, easier and will give you a much better start to learning how to code in a more common manner. I would discontinue learning AS2 and move onto AS3 if you're just starting out.

Answer (score 0):

You have active button - and rollOver action. This is normal in as2. You must write code to tur it off when popUp is active. Mix of components and basic mc-based movies/buttons will always work that.

Answer (score 0):

The rollover event is dispatched whether there are elements over your object or not in AS2 - you might need to set the `_visible` property on the button to `false` while the dialogue is up and then set it back to `true` when it's closed.